Minimal Lie algebra from summing generator terms (specific for su(2^n) with Pauli matrices)
Let $iH = \sum_j ih_j$ be a skew-Hermitian operator made up of tensor products of Pauli matrices $h_i = P_1 \otimes P_2 \otimes .. \otimes P_n$ with $P_i \in \{X, Y, Z, I\}$ (i.e. elements of $\mathfrak{su}(2^n)$ but without the imaginary factor $i$).
We can take the terms $\{ih_1, .., ih_k\}$ as the generators of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \langle \{ ih_1, .., ih_k \}\rangle_\text{Lie} = \{ih_1, ..., ih_{|\mathfrak{g}|} \}$, where the Lie closure $\langle \cdot \rangle_\text{Lie}$ completes the set of generators under commutation. Let us call this the canonical Lie algebra.
I am interested in generating a smaller Lie algebra than the canonical Lie algebra by combining terms of $\{h_i\}$ and treat them as one generator.
There is the trivial case of just taking $\{H\}$ as the set of generators, which trivially leads to $\mathfrak{g} = \{H\}$.
There are other examples of non-trivial reductions, e.g. for $H_\text{Heisenberg} = XXI + YYI + ZZI + IXX + IYY + IZZ$ we can take $\{XXI + YYI + ZZI, IXX + IYY + IZZ\}$ leading to a 4-dimensional Lie algebra, instead of 15 for the canonical Lie algebra.
Another way is to take $\{XXI+IXX, YYI+IYY, ZZI+IZZ\}$ which leads to dimension 8.
I want to understand the underlying mechanism and if there is a constructive and more general way to do these sort of reductions. Not expecting a definite answer, any pointers to results in that direction would be appreciated!
